# Redirect if not in role

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I am starting my first project with **Blazor WebAssembly *(WASM)*** and part of the design is to have a section of the application restricted for administrators use only.  If a user does access a restricted page (by a bookmark / direct URL / broswer history) they are to be redirected back to the Home page.

*Note: `NavLinks` to restricted pages are not visible for an unqualified role.  The only way to access the restricted page is via direct URL, bookmark, history, etc.  Redirection needs to be in place on the restricted pages if a users access is revoked (and they attempt to use a saved bookmark, etc).*

I have a separate API project which users authenticate with. A users successful login will be issued a Bearer Token containing the role, etc, within the payload. This works correctly and I am able to extract the role data from the claim within the Blazor application.

On the Blazor app, for the `.razor` pages that are restricted to administrators, to redirect an unqualified role, I have tried:

```
@page "/administrator.menu"

<RedirectIfNotAdmin />

<h1>Administrator Options</h1>
```

RedirectIfNotAdmin.razor

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="Administrator">
  <NotAuthorized>
    <RedirectTo Page="/" />
  </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I have noticed that this approach seems to 'flash' all the page content after the  `RedirectIfNotAdmin` tag, very briefly showing the `h1` and then redirecting the user (if not an administrator).  *Note*: the `RedirectTo` tag is a separate custom page component I have written.  This approach feels very clunky and is slow.

My solution (for the time being) has been to create a custom page component `RedirectIfNotRole`:

```
@code {

    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Role { get; set; } = "Administrator";
    [Parameter]
    public string RedirectToPage { get; set; } = "/";
    [Parameter]
    public bool ForceLoad { get; set; } = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        if (AuthenticationStateTask.Result.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type.Contains("role")).FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString() != Role) {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo(RedirectToPage, ForceLoad);
        }
    }

}
```

To use this, all I need to do is add the `<RedirectIfNotRole Role="Administrator" Page="/" />` tag to each of the restricted pages.  **I do not get the page 'flash' with this**, and it seems to work and is fast.  That said, **I have some doubts** if this is the best way to get the result I am after.

I did consider creating a administration base class and in the `OnInitializedAsync` lifecycle event implement the redirect.  All the restricted pages would just need to inherit from the base class.  Again, I am unsure if this would be a good approach.

**My question: Is there a better way to implement a fast, simple redirection for roles that are not qualified to access a page?**

I am looking to improve my understanding of Blazor WASM would appreciate thoughts, views or solutions.

To add, I have spent several hours looking for an answer that feels suitable.  As my knowledge of Blazor WASM is in the early stages, I could be overlooking the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a year+ old, but I am having a similar problem. I am just looking to redirect to a page after logging in based on user role. The user is authenticated with OIDC (auth0). The following causes similar behavior to yours (tries to redirect but seems to be instantly overwritten):

```
@code{
    @inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    async void OnAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        var authState = await (task);
        var user = authState.User;
        if (user.Identity is null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return;

        if (user.IsInRole(ApplicationRoles.Administrator))
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/AdministratorDashboard");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried putting this is App.razor as well as MainLayout. The only way I can get it to work is if I cheat and add `await Task.Delay(500)` before the `NavigateTo(...)` call...

Edit: Solved by using the `OnLogInSucceeded` callback for the `RemoteAuthenticatorView` component. In Authentication.razor (taken from any OIDC sample you might find):

```
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="RoleBasedRedirect">
    <LogOut>
        @{
            Logout();
        }
    </LogOut>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>
```

...

```
private async void RoleBasedRedirect(RemoteAuthenticationState state)
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        if (user.Identity is null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return;

        if (user.IsInRole(ApplicationRoles.Administrator))
        {
            state.ReturnUrl = "/AdministratorDashboard";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, this is great, I'll give this a test on my next revision!  Thank you for taking the time to reply 